# SQL Server LEFT OUTER JOIN to sub query without parameter - Nested Loops Join?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that joins to a sub query. When an indexed nvarchar column is passed in as a string literal, the performance tanks. However, when I pass in the same value as a parameter, the execution plan changes drastically and the query executes quickly. I apologize for naming.

In the situation below, `myStringColumn` is indexed and the tables have millions of rows.

This one is bad:

```
SELECT myColumn from myTable1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
        (SELECT myColumn2 from myTable2
         WHERE myStringColumn = 'myFilter') ON...
```

This one is good:

```
Declare @myParameter as nvarchar = N'myFilter'
SELECT myColumn from myTable1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
        (SELECT myColumn2 from myTable2
         WHERE myStringColumn = @myParameter) ON...
```

What I do not understand is why the performance of the second is so much better. From what I can tell, it's because the nested loops join in the plan is much better in the second query, but I do not understand why. My guess is that for some reason SQL Server is having to loop through more rows for each iteration in the first, but I am at a loss as to why only changing to a parameter vs a string literal would have that much affect.

Questions: Why is the second query better than the first? What is SQL Server doing that makes the first so much slower?

Thank you.

Comment: Does performance tank if you declare your string constant as unicode `SELECT myColumn2 from myTable2
         WHERE myStringColumn = N'myFilter'` <-- note the difference, `N` before `'`. Post the plans if it does..

Comment: Yes, the performance is still bad with `N'myFilter'`. I apologize, I am not able to post the plans due to proprietary standards with my organization. My queries above are simplified for this reason. Apologies again if that is bad stackoverflow practice.

Comment: Not easy to help without the plans. Run it again with N; did the performance improve on second and subsequent runs? Make a demo table that reproduces the issue and post the plan of that if you're bothered about sensitive data

Comment: Sorry again for not being able to post the plans. The execution plan is exactly the same if I do `myStringColumn = N'myFilter'`  and `myStringColumn = 'myFilter'`

I cleared the procedure cache between runs.

Comment: Varchar and Nvarchar are part of the same *type family* and you won't see an explicit convert, this type of implicit convert is done in the join operator itself.

Comment: So if I am understanding correctly, when I use a parameter it only has to do the implicit conversion once, but when I pass in the literal string it has to do it for each row?

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that when you declare parameter you doing it correctly with N prefix and declaring variable as **N**varchar, same as your column.
While when you do WHERE - you are not adding N prefix, so internally **varchar** variable created, if you would do `myStringColumn = N'myFilter'` it would work the same way.

Now why is this happening and why it is important to match column type to parameters you passing - is because if parameter is not of column type, then SQL will convert ALL values in the column (so basically all rows) to the type of parameter passed in query (not other way around) - so that's why you have huge performance problem, basically index is lost in this case, cause all column values are being **CONVERTED** to varchar.

Here are some more explanations - https://www.sqlshack.com/query-performance-issues-on-varchar-data-type-using-an-n-prefix/